# Hangfire jobs utilising Autofac IoC singletons sharing a interface

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, singleton, autofac, hangfire

I cant seem to find any information about this and hope someone can help.

With a class "TestClass" inheriting ITestClass I can register an Autofac singleton with the following code:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass>().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();
```

Adding a job to Hangfire is just as easy:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ITestClass>(x => x.MethodInITestClass, Cron.MinuteInterval(1));
```

What I cant seem to figure out is how to register multiple classes as Autofac singletons *all having the same interface* and being able to create a Hangfire job for a specific singleton.

For instance, having an interface named ITest and classes TestClass1, TestClass2 and TestClass3 utilising this interface I would like to add a Hangfire job for TestClass2.

I thought maybe named singletons would be a solution which can be created easily:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass1>().Named<ITest>("TestClass1").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<TestClass2>().Named<ITest>("TestClass2").SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<TestClass3>().Named<ITest>("TestClass3").SingleInstance();
```

However, adding a Hangfire job for TestClass2 seems impossible as Hangfire only takes a interface as an argument and the interface now has 3 related singletons.

I would also like to be able to resolve all singletons implementing this interface into a IEnumerable which also seems impossible with named singletons.

Any advice on this? I guess named singletons may be a dead end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think named or keyed services will help you here. I took a look at the [JobActivator](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.Core/JobActivator.cs) implementation and there does not seem to be a way to have the name or key available in the `ActivateJob(Type jobType)` method where the service is resolved.

> However, adding a Hangfire job for TestClass2 seems impossible as Hangfire only takes a interface as an argument and the interface now has 3 related singletons.

I don't think this is correct, so you could use your singleton types (`TestClass1`, `TestClass2`, ...) directly when adding a job. To do so you would have to register your singletons `AsSelf()` as well:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass>().AsSelf().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();
```

You'll still be able to resolve all your singletons using the `ITestClass` interface. If you don't have access to your singleton types in the code where you are adding the job you'll have to add an interface for each singleton (`ITestClass1`, `ITestClass2`, ...) and then use these interfaces for creating the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer fknx! :)

I see that by registering like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass1>().AsSelf().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<TestClass2>().AsSelf().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<TestClass3>().AsSelf().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();
```

.. would enable me to resolve them all using the ITestClass. What I don't see is how I would be able to register a Hangfirejob for i.e. TestClass2?

Your proposal for solution if I don't have access to singleton types is working great!

Registering:

```
builder.RegisterType<TestClass1>().As<ITestClass1>().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<TestClass2>().As<ITestClass2>().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<TestClass3>().As<ITestClass3>().As<ITestClass>().SingleInstance();
```

Also, I have ITestClassX inheriting ITestClass so that if I resolve by ITestClassX or ITestClass I still have access to the same methods.

Adding a Hangfire job:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ITestClass2>("JobTitle", x => x.DoAJob(), Cron.MinuteInterval(5));
```